# About dropbox api for getting accounts list from dropbox teams

Tags: dropbox-api

I want to get the Information about to have an admin dropbox account which has multiple dropbox account under it. In the available APIs there are no API given for User   provisioning or which will give me users accounts available of one admin account. So can anybody tell me right way to do it ?

Comment: any update on this one? been over a year. Did the API change yet?

Answer (score 0):

The Dropbox API does not currently offer any such Teams specific or user provisioning functions.

Comment: any update on this one? been over a year. Did the API change yet?